# Cocos creator не билдит проект под Android

Tags: android, build, cocos, cocos2d-x

Имеется:
Cocos creator v. 1.9.3 (далее CC), NDK, SDK, Apatch ANT, Android studio, проект, написанный на javascript нормально собранный и работающий на web-desktop.

Все необходимые ресурсы подключены к СС (NDK, SDK, ANT\bin), настройки выставлены следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако при попытке собрать билд, билдер просто зависает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки билда пробовал выставлять самые разные, как и закачивать различные версии SDK и ANT

Comment: Обновил cocos creator до версии 1.10 и все нормально скомпилилось